# Unhighlight row returns a max int on indexpath when user scrolls table with a cell highlighted

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UILabel as subview of my cell. When user highlight a cell the label text change it's color and when the cell is unhighlighted the color changes back, just like an usual cell textLabel.

The problem is that if the user tap a cell and scroll the table the cell will unhighlight, the unhighlight delegate method will be called but it will return [2147483647, 2147483647] as index path and the text will not change, as there is no cell on that index path.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
      NSInteger section = [indexPath section];

      //only change the text on cells at section 1

      if (section == 1) {
          //get cell with given index path 
          UITableViewCell *currentCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
          // retrieve the UILabel by it's tag
          UILabel *cellLabel = (UILabel *)[currentCell viewWithTag:1011];
          cellLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
      }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
      NSInteger section = [indexPath section];
      if (section == 1) {
          UITableViewCell *currentCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
          UILabel *cellLabel = (UILabel *)[currentCell viewWithTag:1011];
          [cellLabel performSelector:@selector(setTextColor:) withObject:[UIColor lightGrayColor] afterDelay:0.2f];
      }
}
```

How can i retrieve the correct cell to change it's UILabel subview text when the user scrolls table with a cell highlighted?

Comment: In place of [cellLabel performSelector:@selector(setTextColor:) withObject:[UIColor lightGrayColor] afterDelay:0.2f]. You can write cellLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

Comment: Even if i do that the problem remains. I call the method with a delay because when user taps the cell the change of colors happens too fast to be noticed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing those methods I had the same strange results for the `indexPath` (no idea, why these methods are not working properly).

But I would suggest to just write your own `UITableViewCell` subclass and override the following method (that is called every time a cell gets selected/deselected):

```
- (void) setSelected : (BOOL) selected animated : (BOOL) animated {
    [super setSelected: selected animated: animated];
    // your customisations to your UILabel
    if (selected == NO) {
        self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    } 
}
```

Hope this answer helps you out with your problem

Comment: That's a great idea, probably will work. However i trying to avoid not to use a subclass for my cell, but if i can't do it in any other way i will try the subclass.